# Admin Category Custom Attribute not saved

Tags: admin, custom-attributes, magento2.4

There are quite a few questions similar to this one, but I can't get any answers to work.

I run Magento 2.4.2 and tried to add a custom attribute with the instruction here:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/howto/add_category_attribute.html

I have created the two required files in my module (`InstallData.php` and `category_form.xml`) with the following differences:

InstallData.php:

```
     public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
     {
         $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
-        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'attribute_id', [
+        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'myattribute', [
             'type'     => 'int',
-            'label'    => 'Your Category Attribute Name',
+            'label'    => 'My Category Attribute Name',
             'input'    => 'boolean',
             'source'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
             'visible'  => true,
```

```
 <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
     <fieldset name="display_settings">
-        <field name="attribute_id">
+        <field name="myattribute">
             <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                     <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
-                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Category Attribute Name</item>
+                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Category Attribute Name</item>
                     <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                     <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                         <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
```

After running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `bin/magento c:c` the user interface shows the checkbox:

[image: new checkbox]

So the overall procedure went fine. But now I try to change the value of the checkbox and save the default category by clicking on the red "Save" button on the top right, the checkbox state is not saved and restored back to off.

Where can I start looking for the error?

Answer (score 0):

I have just created an attribute and add it to the category form. Please check the below file.

> InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**  
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
    
    /**  
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /**
         * Adding attribute myattribute in the category
         */
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'myattribute',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
                'input' => 'select',
                'sort_order' => 333,
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'global' => 1,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

> category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="myattribute">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Attribute</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Please check and let me still if you facing any issues.

Comment: I see the custom attribute in the “General” section, but I can't save its state. It always gets back to "no".

Comment: Please given the code and check. It's working fine in Magento setup.

Comment: I have used your code  and run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` afterwards

Comment: did you get any errors? Please check logs.

Comment: Because no need to do anything else to save the category field value. Please try in the fresh setup so you will get more idea.

Comment: I didn't get any errors. I will try with a fresh install and report back. Thank you so far.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can resoled you problem?, I'm following this tutorial https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-category-attributes-programmatically/ but not work, create the field but not saved information to display in view of category

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.